# Как избавиться от ошибки Индекс находился вне границ массива?

Tags: c#, массивы

Как сделать так, чтобы не выдавало ошибку

> Индекс находился вне границ массива.

при отсутствии нуля. То есть какое 2 условие нужно?

```
using System;

namespace whileHomeWork
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int[] intArray = {2, 3, 5, 9, 4, 7, 2};
            int index = 0;
            while (intArray[index] != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(intArray[index]);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: index < intArray.Length

Comment: пробовал! нужно что бы если есть ноль то цикл остановился а, если нет то дошёл до конца и остановился.

Comment: что конкретно пробовал? Какой код?

Comment: while (intArray[index] != 0 || index < intArray.Length)

Comment: поменяйте || на &&

Comment: пробовал! не работает!

Comment: А так? `while (index < intArray.Length && intArray[index] != 0)`

Comment: @DmitryD. точно, а я проглядел :)

Comment: Да так тоже пробовал вроде! не работало! А, сейчас ещё раз попробовал сработало! Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте дополнить условие цикла так:

```
while (index < intArray.Length && intArray[index] != 0)
```